# Personalizable web part custom property not shown for users with Contribute permission level

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I've create the Web Part for SharePoint 2010, which contains simple custom property with `PersonalizationScope.User`. 
Web part inherited from the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart`

```
private int _mainBodyBorderWidth = 0;
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User),
     WebBrowsable(true),
     WebDisplayName("Main Body Border Width"),
     WebDescription("Set main body border width"),
     Category("Style")]
    public int MainBodyBorderWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return _mainBodyBorderWidth;
        }
        set
        {
            _mainBodyBorderWidth = value;
        }
    }
```

When Site Administrator or users with permission **Add and Customize Pages** click **"Personalize Page"** and than **"Edit My Web Part"** this property is displayed in the web part tool pane. However users with standard permission level **"Contribute"** can't see this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this article](http://www.kiruthik.com/2010/10/05/YouDontHaveAddAndCustomizePagesPermissionsRequiredToPerformThisAction.aspx) and some investigation I get following results about `SafeContol` tag for the web part. The following considerations must be applied for the web part which user without permission **Add and Customize Pages** can add/remove or modify.

1. In SP 2010 `TypeName` attribute of the tag should use particular type name instead wildcard.
2. Attribute `Safe` set to **"True"**
3. Attribute `SafeAgainstScript` also set to **"True"**
   And SafeControl tag will look similar to this:

`<SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" TypeName="ListViewWebPart" Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="True" />`

However VS 2010 by default generate wildcard **"*"** for the `TypeName` attribute, and **"False"** value for the `SafeAgainstScript` attribute of the **Web Part** item. So you need change in the **Web Part** item Properties **Safe Control Entries** collection entry with particular type name and "SafeAgainstScript" property right value.